# Move a Row from One Table to Another Through Change of a Cell in that Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of orders with a column for order status. Once the order has been marked as "completed", I want to move the order (row in the table) to another table on another sheet.

I have been struggling to get the event trigger.

I can display the row of the change relative to the worksheet. I am trying to get the row number relative to the table in order to move the exact row. I created a named range for the order status column so that I can set "Target" to that.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim statuscolumn As Range
Set statuscolumn = Range("OrderStatusInCXTable")

If Target = "Completed" Then MsgBox Target.row

End Sub
```

When I move a table row from one table to another, I don't care about the position of the row respective. It could be 5th in table 1 and be 1st in table 2. I just want to transfer it from table 1 to 2 on another sheet.

I want to copy and paste the row from table 1 to table 2. Then delete the row from table 1.

I was thinking to use Worksheet_change to see when an order (row in table 1) has been marked as completed. When it has been marked as completed, Worksheet_change will notice the event, find the specific row, copy from table 1 to table 2, and finally delete it from table 1.

Comment: I would want the moved data to be placed in the next free row. So, the only reason you want the row number relative to the table is that the 'resulting' table should have the same positions of data as the 'initial' table (of orders). Try to figure out how moving of data should be done: is the data copied and pasted into the resulting table and then deleted from the initial table? Do you calculate the last column, or use column as number or letter in the initial table, and the same for the resulting table... You can edit your post (question) any time and elaborate a little bit more.